# how to telnet to a computer in a Lan

Tags: node.js, tcp, telnet

I have created a TCP server using node.js

The server run on port 8xxx.

I've tested the server using telnet on iPad, it's OK.

The computer which runs the server and the iPad use the same wifi network.

The wireless router is connected to a VDSL Modem which is connect to the Internet.

How to telnet the TCP server using another computer not in my LAN?

I'm new to networking. Please show me how :) Thanks!

P/s: Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any firewall blocking incoming connections, you should be able to connect to your TCP server with your WAN IP and the port you configure.

You can find you IP by visiting website like: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Then, try to connect from remote computer with something like `telnet  [YOUR IP] [PORT]`

If connection don't work, please disable every software firewall and/or material firewall and it should work properly.

Comment: I think the IP logged by the website http://whatismyipaddress.com was the IP of the VDSL Modem, isn't it? I still can not connect to the server via telnet

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need the public IP for your computer (Server). Normally the public IP changes every  time you login to the ISP client.
You can find your IP by using whatismyip.org.

Now, the other machine should also have internet connection. Then telnet using the public ip that you got from whatismyip. It will work.

Comment: Also, as right suggested by DaFunix, there should be no firewall blocking the request, but since your LAN connections are working, WAN should also work.

Comment: I think the IP address I got from the website was the Modem IP Address. I still can not telnet the server. When I connect to the IP via browser, it require log in. It seemed to be the log-in form of the modem.

Comment: ohh..is it a Wi-Fi modem ? In some cases you need to do port forwarding. Please search for port forwarding specific to your modem. Because what is happening here I guess is that the Public IP is giving you the configuration page of you modem which wont help.

Comment: yes, it's the configuration page of my modem. Somebody told me that I need to do some port forwarding. Let me try :). Thanks Ajit